# How to shift column name to result set in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
 SELECT 
    count(CASE WHEN fan_gate.genre = 'Breaks' THEN fan_gate.id END) AS 'Breaks',
    count(CASE WHEN fan_gate.genre = 'Cill Out' THEN fan_gate.id END) AS 'Chill Out',
    count(CASE WHEN fan_gate.genre = 'Deep House' THEN fan_gate.id END) AS 'Deep House',
    count(CASE WHEN fan_gate.genre = 'Drum & Bass' THEN fan_gate.id END) AS 'Drum & Bass'
FROM fan_gate
```

Current result set

```
Breaks  | Cill Out  |Deep House  |Drum & Bass
------------------------------------------------
  4581  |    785    | 7858       |   4474
```

I need

```
Column 1    | column 2
-----------------------
Breaks      | 4581
Cill Out    |  785
Deep House  | 7858
Drum & Bass | 4474
```

Comment: Don't you need to use back-ticks to delimit the column aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want `group by`:

```
SELECT fg.genre, COUNT(*)
FROM fan_gate fg
GROUP BY fg.genre;
```

If you only care about those four genres, then add a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY` to select the ones you care about.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fan_gate.genre as column1,count(fan_gate.genre) as column2
FROM fan_gate
group by fan_gate.genre
```

Comment: Please add some basic description to describe logic behind your answer.